# Resource file(.R) cannot be resolved in content view Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I m getting error at setcontentview, its not taking layout main.Resource file is doesn't created can anybody solve my problem.

here is my code for main screen.

SqlitetestActivity.java file

```
public class SqlitetestActivity extends ListActivity {
protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;  
protected ListAdapter adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StudentDetails.class);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void search(View view) {
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                    new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            R.layout.employee_list_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:paddingTop="4dp">

<include android:id="@+id/search" layout="@layout/search" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried restarting eclipse.. this doest work. any able to solve this problem. please insist me.. thanks in adbvance

Comment: what error you r getting can just post your error log so we can find whats going wrong

Comment: did you try to clean and build the project?

Comment: m nt gettin error.. coz prgm doent run..

Comment: try to close the project and reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take 2 steps and problem would be more likely to get solved:

> Step 1: Clean your project by clicking Project -> Clean.
>
> Step 2: Rebuild your project by clicking Project -> Build All.

Also make sure that your layout xml files are syntax error free and you don't have any image which has non-acceptable names (such as a "-" between image name).

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you are importing the correct R file.

If there is an import for android.R... delete it and clean your project.